# Display mountain names at lower zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How can I display layers that by default seem hidden to show at lower zoom levels? For example, I am trying to display mountain names ("poi-parks-scalerank1") at zoom level lower than 10. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to show vector tile data at zoom levels lower than the tiles in which it is physically present. For instance, if the mountain names only exist at zoom 10 and above (that is, any vector tiles at /9/x/y.pbf don't have them), there's nothing you can do to force Mapbox-GL-JS to render them.

(The reverse is not true: you can "overzoom" vector tiles by setting `maxzoom` on the layer.)

It's possible (but very unlikely - Mapbox's tiles are pretty optimised) that the data exists in a lower level than the style actually calls for, so you might as well have a go, as leelum1 suggests.

Otherwise, you will have to obtain the mountain name information somehow and create your own layer, then style it.